# Climatology frequencies and duration

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

I have a 10 years climatological dateset as follows.

```
dt               T          P
01-01-2010        3          0
02-01-2010        5          11
03-01-2010       10          50
....
31-12-2020       -1          0
```

I want to estimate the total number of days in each month where T and P continuously stayed greater than 0 for three days or more

I would want these columns as an output:

```
month    Number of days/DurationT&P>0     T   P
```

I have never used loops in python, I seem to be able to write a simple loop and nothing beyond this when the data has to be first grouped by month and year and then apply the condition.  would really appreciate any hints on the construction of the loop.

```
A= dataset
A['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(A['dt'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

for column in A [['P', 'T']]:
    for i in range (len('P')):
        if i > 0:
           P.value_counts()
             print(i)
    for j in range (len ('T')):
       if i > 0:
       T.value_counts()
           print(j)
```

Comment: Could you rewrite the title to focus on the specific technical problem you encountered, rather than the problem domain you were working in when you encountered that specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really naive way you could set it up by simply iterating over the rows:

```py
df['valid'] = (df['T'] > 0) & (df['P'] > 0)

def count_total_days(df):
    i = 0
    total = 0
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.valid:
            i += 1
        elif not row.valid:
            if i >= 3:
                total += i
            i = 0
    
    return total
```

Since you want it per month, you would first have to create new month and year columns to group by:

```py
df['month'] = df['dt'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['dt'].dt.year

for date, df_subset in df.groupby(['month', 'year']):
    count_total_days(df_subset)
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your answer. Can I ask further, how to then add up the instances per month where T&P >0 for three or more consecutive days? Because what I am getting through this piece of code is whether T&P are both >0 for a particular day grouped month,year wise. Rather than the total instances where T&P>0 for three or more consecutive days.

Comment: This provides the total number of days that T&P>0, only counting days that are part of a 3+ day consecutive streak. If instead of counting the total days you want the total consecutive streaks, change the line `total += i` to `total += 1` (this will increment one count per streak instead of `i` days per streak).

Comment: Hi again, I tried with your suggestion, it produces exactly the same results. Could I ask if it is possible to count total number of instances that T&P stays>0 for three consecutive days or more and then output that to a new column called total? instead of the True and False. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample` and `sum` to get the sum of day for each where the condition is true.

```
import pandas as pd

dt = ["01-01-2010", "01-02-2010","01-03-2010","01-04-2010", "03-01-2010",'12-31-2020']
t=[3,66,100,5,10,-1]
P=[0,77,200,11,50,0]

A=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dt, t,P)),
               columns =['dtx', 'T','P'])

A['dtx'] = pd.to_datetime(A['dtx'], format='%m-%d-%Y')
A['Mask']=A.dtx.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
dict_freq=A['Mask'].value_counts().to_dict()
newdict = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict_freq.items() if v >= 3)
A=A[A['Mask'].isin(list(newdict.keys()))]
A['Mask']=(A['T'] >= 1) & (A['P'] >= 1)
df_summary=A.query('Mask').resample(rule='M',on='dtx')['Mask'].sum()
```

Which produce

```
2010-01-31    3
```

Comment: This solution is not taking into account the requirement to only count three consecutive days of the condition `T>0 & P>0`.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz,thanks for the comment, edit has been made

Comment: You still need to group by both month and year, as described in the final paragraph of the question.

Comment: Hi Balandongiv, Thanks for helping out. The code does provide the total number of days per month where both T&P >0, but doesn't provide the instances/frequencies of only those days where T&P are consecutively >0

Comment: doesn't provide the instances/frequencies of only those days where T&P are >0 for three consecutive days.